# Shiny - how to coloring border cell table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

i have a simple table and want to display in shiny. but in default setting, the border cell is transparant. this is the code...

```
output$tabel <-renderUI({
tabel1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),2,3)
list(
renderTable(tabel1)
)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Shiny is just a wrapper for R to output R code into HTML code. You will have to determine exactly what class the table is created with, but checking [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html) shows that it should be `shiny-html-output` and then  you should have a `<table>` in there. Should probably have a class of `shiny-table-output`, but I didn't find proof of that.

However, when ever you figure that out you just need to either add a style sheet to your R. And in that style sheet you will do your CSS.

IF it is `shiny-html-output` and `shiny-table-output` it would be as simple as:

```
.shiny-html-output .shiny-table-output{ border: 1px solid #000; }
```

IF it is just `shiny-html-output` and a `table` then same thing above, but `.shiny-html-output table` instead.

That would be it. Do try to use developer tools to inspect the elements of the browser when you have them up. F12 in most browsers or Right click inspect is all you have to do.